# How to get Syncthing working in macOS?

Tags: macos, sync, osx-yosemite

I want to install a sync service between phone (Android) and laptop (macOS/OS X). I’m not a big fan of Dropbox, so I’ve tried [Resilio](https://www.resilio.com/platforms/mobile/) (aka: BTSync). That worked for me until recently, but with the completely new setup I cannot get it working. I don’t know what it is, but the phone and laptop won’t connect. So I removed it from phone and laptop, including the local profile, although I'm not sure that succeeded.

Then I installed [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net). On my Mac, the browser opens at `127.0.0.1:8080` and displays a login screen. This is the htauth type, not a webpage with a login. I don’t know the password, don’t even know if this is from Syncthing or from something else. I can’t find a default login for this.

What I would like is to be able to completely remove Syncthing and start all over, or get the login working. The login service may be from something else; no idea.

So I hope anyone can give me tips how to handle this.

Comment: From what I remember the GUI for synching runs on port 8384. Try opening the browser to localhost:8384

Answer (score 1):

If the GUI configuration page is asking for authentication and you don't know the credentials, see the FAQ for how to reset:

https://docs.syncthing.net/users/faq.html#how-do-i-reset-the-gui-password

> If you’ve forgotten/lost the GUI password, you can remove it by deleting the **<user>** and **<password>** XML tags from the **<gui>** block in file `config.xml`. This should be done while Syncthing is not running. The location of the file depends on the OS and is described in the configuration documentation.

As noted, the [configuration documentation](https://docs.syncthing.net/users/config.html) tells you how to find the `config.xml` file:

> Syncthing uses a single directory to store configuration and crypto keys. Syncthing also has a database, which is often stored in this directory too. The config location defaults to `$HOME/.config/syncthing` (Unix-like), `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Syncthing` (Mac), or `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Syncthing` (Windows). It can be changed at runtime using the `--config` flag.

You can also display the configuration file directories from a command line interface by running the Syncthing binary with the `--paths` option ([reference](https://docs.syncthing.net/users/syncthing.html#cmdoption-paths)).

If you really want to "wipe out" the Syncthing configuration and start fresh, just rename the `Syncthing` configuration directory (e.g., to `Syncthing.000`) or delete it while Syncthing is not running and start Syncthing again.